# PHP's SimpleXML not handling &#8217 ; properly

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I'm parsing an RSS feed that has an `&#8217;` in it. SimpleXML turns this into a â€™. What can I do to stop this?

Just to answer some of the questions that have come up - I'm pulling an RSS feed using CURL. If I output this directly to the browser, the `&#8217;` displays as ’ which is what's expected. When I create a new SimpleXMLElement using this, (e.g. `$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($raw_feed);` and dump the `$xml` variable, every instance of `&#8217;` is replaced with â€™.

It appears that SimpleXML is having trouble with UTF-8 ampersand encoded characters. (The XML declaration specifies UTF-8.)

I do have control over the feed after CURL has retrieved the feed before it's used to construct a SimpleXML element.

Comment: After you parse it, what are you doing with the value(s)? Saving to a DB or displaying it on the browser?

Comment: What do you expect it to look like?

Comment: &#8217; or &rsquo; "right single quotation mark" Do you have any control over the RSS?

Comment: maybe include your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came down to having to set the default encoding to UTF-8 in four places:

1. The default locale at the head of the file: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');`
2. Encoding the string that comes out of CURL: `utf8_encode($string);`
3. Setting the MySQL connection to use UTF-8 by default: `mysqli_set_charset($database_insert_connection, 'utf8');`
4. Setting the appropriate collation in the MySQL database to `utf8_general_ci`

If outputting to the browser, setting the appropriate header (e.g. `header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`)

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 2):

`&#8217;` represents the Unicode character `’` (U+2019) that is encoded with 0xE28099 in UTF-8. And when that byte sequence is interpreted with [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), it represents the characters `â` (0xE2), `€` (0x80), and `™` (0x99).

That means SimpleXML handles the input as UTF-8 encoded but you interpret its output as Windows-1252. And unless you really want to use Windows-1252, you are probably just missing to [specify the character encoding of your output properly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2).